# Am I using the correct syntax for trimWeights()?

Tags: r, survey

I'm fairly new to RStudio, but I'm trying to learn the survey package for work purposes. I'm trying to adjust the weights of a `svydesign` object using the `trimWeights` function. This is the code I'm using so far.

```
library(survey)
library(tidyverse)
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre1.8.0_201')

library(xlsx)

allsurveys = read.csv('allsurveys.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")

> head(allsurveys)
   case         daytype family 
1 36846 3 VA October WD     No  
2 36847 3 VA October WD     No   
3 36848 3 VA October WD     No   
4 36849 3 VA October WD     No   
5 36850 3 VA October WD    Yes   
6 36852 3 VA October WD     No 

daytype.table = read.csv('daytype_counts.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE, fileEncoding="UTF-8-BOM")

> head(daytype.table)
                              daytype   freq
1                     3 VA October WD 179786
2                     3 VA October WE  58237
3 3 VA October WE Autumn Half-term SH  54578
4 3 VA October WD Autumn Half-term SH  70652
5                    3 VA November WD 193441
6                    3 VA November WE  98562

allsurveys$daytype = factor(allsurveys$daytype)
allsurveys$family  = factor(allsurveys$family)

N = sum(daytype.table$freq)
na = nrow(allsurveys)
max.a = (3*N)/na
min.a = (0.3*N)/na

des.a = svydesign(ids = ~1,
                  strata = NULL,
                  fpc = rep(N,na),
                  data = allsurveys
                  )

ps.des.a <- postStratify(design = des.a, strata = ~daytype, population = daytype.table)
ps.des.c <- postStratify(design = des.c, strata = ~daytype, population = daytype.table)

ps.des.a.trim <- trimWeights(ps.des.a, lower=min.a, upper=max.c, strict=TRUE)
ps.des.c.trim <- trimWeights(ps.des.c, lower=min.c, upper=min.c, strict=TRUE)
```

The `trimWeights` function does run and creates a new `svydesign` object but the upper limit doesn't seem to apply correctly. If I look at the weights using `list(ps.des.a.trim$postStrata)` I get some weights at the bottom that are over the `max.a` I had set. I not really sure what's going wrong here. Is it because the I'm trying to trim the weights on a `svydesign` that has been weighted using `postStratify`?

Comment: Add some data so that we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Took out some unnecessary bits of code. The allsurveys.csv contains case level data tagged by the day type when the survey was completed. The daytype_counts.csv contains frequency for each day type that is used for the post stratification weighting. Hope that clears things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the weights as follows :

```
weights(ps.des.a.trim)
```

I actually noticed the same thing that you are referring to, and it was a bit weird. However, if you apply the `svymean` function or such functions, the results take into account the trimmed weights. Not the old ones.